# Visual Studio debug window strips output

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to develop a C# Application.
It retrieves a Shoutcast Stream. It reads 256 Bytes in each loop-cycle and is supposed to write them to the debug-output.
They are stripped badly.

Could this be due to some Unicode-signs? How can I make output-window-safe Strings which won't get stripped?

Comment: perhaps edit your question with the streaming code with the output?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you're writing them out, which makes it hard to know what's wrong.

If you're reading binary data, I would personally write that out in hex. [`BitConverter.ToString(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) will do that very simply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it won't write them out ever, or just delayed?  You can flush the stream to force it to write immediately.